# Как добавить объекты в файл JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Всем привет, не поможете решить проблему с JSON?

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const block = fs.readFileSync("block.json", "utf-8")
const id = replyHandler.text
const value = {
  [id]: {
    "name": [id],
    "reason": "махинации"
  }
}
var obj = JSON.parse(block);
obj.push(value);
block = JSON.stringify(obj)

fs.writeFileSync('block.json', block)
```

Я использую метод .push, но как известно - этот метод можно использовать для работы с массивами. И значение value, которое я объявляю в коде возможно упомянуть только в фигурных скобках, но тогда в файле JSON, он будет тоже со скобками. Сам JSON файл выглядит таким образом:

```js
{
  "898836403": {
    "name": "898836403",
    "reason": "тест"
  }
}
```

Мне нужно записывать значения, как на примере выше. Помогите, пожалуйста, уже пол дня пытаюсь это реализовать.
Мне нужно понять, как записать объект и содержащиеся в нём ключи=значения

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: «проблема с тем-то» — это плохой заголовок.

Comment: Изменил заголовок.

Comment: `obj[id] = {
    "name": id,
    "reason": "махинации"
  }`  всё же вам надо вначале почитать книжку для новичков прежде чем делать что-то.... А как это делать я вам в прошлом вопросе написал. и в документации это написано. и даже примеры есть в самом начале статьи.  Пол дня мучиться не надо. Надо просто вначале изучить основы.

Comment: Всё-таки смог сделать. Тем не менее, благодарю вас за наставления, без них бы я дня 2 ковырялся.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const id = "123";
const reason = "abuse";

const blacklist = require("./block.json");

blacklist[id] = {
  name: id,
  reason: reason
}

require("fs").writeFileSync('block.json', JSON.stringify(blacklist));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]